# Query categories that have a description

Tags: hooks, sitemap

I want to query the categories and tags that have a description to make sure only those are listed in the sitemap. The `description__like` argument used by [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) is the closest I've gotten to it.

```php
// Clean sitemap
// https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-the-archive-pages-from-the-sitemap/

add_filter(
    'wp_sitemaps_taxonomies_query_args',
    function( $args, $taxonomy ) {
        // Show in sitemap categories and topics that have a description
        if ( $taxonomy == 'category' || $taxonomy == 'post_tag' ) {
            # First attempt
            $args['description__like'] = '';

            # Desperate second attempt
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'description',
                'value'   => array(''),
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            );

            # Third attempt: seems to work
            $args['description__like'] = ' ';
        }

        return $args;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

The third approach with the empty space seems to work, but I feel unsure about edge cases as I don't know why it works. Any clue about a more explicit way to do it or is this one OK?

Answer (score 0):

How about looping all available terms, if term has description, add to to an `object_ids`, something like this.

```php
add_filter(
    'wp_sitemaps_taxonomies_query_args',
    function( $args, $taxonomy ) {
        // Show in sitemap categories and topics that have a description
        if ( $taxonomy == 'category' || $taxonomy == 'post_tag' ) {
            // get the terms of the taxonomy
            $terms = get_terms( 'post_tag', [
                'hide_empty' => false, // change to true if you want not empty terms
                'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
            ]);

            // will contain all ids of terms that have description
            $object_ids = [];

            // loop terms
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                // if term has description, add its id to our array
                if (!empty($term->description)) $object_ids[] = $term->term_id;
            }

            // if we have ids (found terms with description) add it to the filter $args
            if (!empty($object_ids)) $args['object_ids'] = $object_ids;
        }

        return $args;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```